# Are there any good techniques for keeping nearly-sorted data nearly-sorted?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, opengl, data-structures, 3d

### Short Version:

I'm looking for a technique to keep nearly-sorted data in nearly-sorted order over time, despite the values changing slightly.

### Here's the scenario:

In the world of 3D graphics, it is often beneficial to order your objects from front-to-back before drawing.  As your scene changes or your view of the scene changes, this data may require re-sorting, however it will usually be very close to the sorted order (i.e. it won't change very much between frames).  It's also not critical that the data be **exactly** in sorted order.  The worst thing that will happen is that a polygon will be rendered and then completely hidden.  It's a small performance hit, but not the end of the world.

With this in mind, is it possible to sort the data once ahead of time and then apply a minimal **patch** to the data once per frame to ensure that the data stays **mostly** sorted?  In this scenario, the data would be considered mostly sorted if most of the objects were in ascending order.  That is, 1 object that is 10 steps away from it's proper location is **much** better (10x better) than 10 objects that are 1 step away from their proper location.

It's also worth noting that the data could continue to be patched on a semi regular basis, as the data is typically rendered 30 times per second (or so).  As long as the calculation was efficient, it could continue to be done over time until the changes stop and the list was completely sorted.

### Existing Idea:

My knee jerk reaction to this problem is:

1. Apply an `n log n` sort to the data when it is loaded, and on large changes (which I can track pretty easily).
2. When the data starts changing slowly (e.g. when the scene is rotated), apply a single (linear) pass of some sort on the data to swap backwards neighbors and try to maintain sort order (I think this is basically shell sort - maybe there is a better algorithm to use for this single pass).
3. Keep doing a single pass of the partial sort each frame until the changes stop and the data is completely sorted
4. Go back to step 2 and wait for more changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it sounds like the sort order changes without you changing the data itself. E.g. you change the camera, so the sort order should change, even though you have not modified any polygons.

If so, you can't detect sort order changes directly when they happen. If you could, I would create buckets for the list of polygons, and resort buckets when 'enough' polygons in that bucket have been touched.

But I'm betting your system doesn't work that way. The sort is determined by the view port. In that case polygons at the front of the sort matter much more than ones at the end.

So I'd segment the poly list into fifths or something like that. Front to back, so that the first fifth is the part closest to the camera. I'd completely sort the first segment every frame. I'd divide the second segment into sub segments - say 5 again - and sort each sub segment every frame, such that every 5 frames the second fifth is completely sorted. segment the third through 5th segments into 15 sub segments and do those every 5 frames each such that the rest get sorted completely every 75 frames. At 60 fps you'd have the display list completely resorted a little more than once per second.

The nice thing about prioritizing the front of the list, is
1. Polys at the front are going to tend to be larger on the screen, and will fail depth test more often. Bad orders at the end of the list will more often than not just not matter.
2. the front of the list is more susceptible sort changes due to camera changes.

Also chose those segment ranges with a little overlap, so that polygons can migrate to their correct segment in 2 sorts.

@OP: Thinking about it a little more. You are probably more concerned with having the sorting cost stay bounded - instead of exploding with scene complexity. Especially since a very complex scene should - surprisingly - be less susceptible to bad sorts ( because generally the polys get smaller ).

You could define a fixed amount of sorting you are willing to do per frame. Use say 50% of the budget for as much of the front of the list as you can afford, 25% of the budget to sort the next region and 25% to spend equally on the rest.

Say you budget 1000 polys sorted per frame, and you have 10000 polys in the scene. Sort the first 500 polys every frame. Sort 250 polys every tenth frame for the next region. So 501-750 on frame 1, 751-1000 on frame 2 etc. And then divide the rest of the list into 250 frame segments and sort them round robin for however many frames you need to.

This keeps the sorting cost fixed s the scene gets more and less complex, and it is easy to tune, you just adjust the sorting budget to what you can afford.

Comment: You are correct, I can't detect which items change without redoing the calculations.  In fact, when a rotate happens, nearly every distance will change (only an object at the pivot location would be excluded).  This is a really interesting idea.  I wonder if anyone has done something like this before.

Comment: Nice ideas, but there are some repairable flaws in the details: you claim that the second segment is completely sorted every 5 frames. This is not true, because your proposal does not allow for mobility *between* sub-segments, only *within*. The best solution in this spirit is probably to replace sorting segment a .. b with sorting segment a-n .. b+n everywhere, where n probably depends on the segment length b-a somehow - e.g. (b-a)/10.

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of sorts that run in O(n) time if the input is mostly sorted, and O(n log n) if the data is not sorted.  It sounds like you can use that pretty easily.  Timsort is one such sort and, I believe, is the default sort now in both python and java.  Smoothsort is another one that is fairly easy to implement yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest a solution that borrows from a number of others here. Of course we start with a full sort of the objects on initialisation.

What I would do is always perform, say, 10 linear-time runs over your objects for every frame (with early termination if you find out that your objects are already completely sorted). Each run can be, say, one pass of [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) with a [shell sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort)-style gap over the whole array: for all i from 0 to n-gap-1, compare A[i] and A[i+gap], and exchange them if they are not sorted. You can use a fixed sequence of gaps, or maybe better, let it vary between frames; either way, if you do sufficiently many frames where the objects do not change, you'll have a fully sorted sequence. You could even mix different types of sub-algorithms to do your runs, as long as each iteration improves the 'sortedness'.

You can add Rafael Baptista's idea of prioritizing the front of the scene easily by doing one extra run on the front segment, or choosing to divide the gap by two for the front half, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work out as neatly as the problem you've supposed because all you have to do is turn the camera 90 degrees and the basis for being sorted is on a different axis entirely. (X and Y axis are independent, for example -- looking down the X axis will cause the sort order to not rely on the X axis, and looking down the Y axis will cause the sort order to not rely on the Y axis.) Even a 5 degree turn can cause far away "close" (as far as Z-order is concerned) things to be suddenly "far".

Let's be honest -- generating the draw calls for the objects is normally going to take much more time than sorting them, especially if you have an optimized sorting algorithm for your scenario and your game is of modern visual complexity.

Sorting can be practically O(n), especially with histogram-based algorithms or radix-style algorithms. (Yes, radix sort applies to integers, so you'd have to scale your world coordinates to integers, but normally that's more than good enough unless you have a gigantic world.)

That being said, since you're already doing O(n) ops for everything you're drawing, resorting per frame isn't going to be a huge problem, especially with both high and low level optimization.

Another common way of addressing this issue is with a [scene graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph), but for your purposes it ends up essentially being a re-sort per frame. However, you can build frustum culling, shadow culling, and level of detail calculations into the scene graph traversal.

If you're looking for approximations, instead of doing a z-distance sort do a true distance sort and update the sort order more often for close by objects and less often for further objects (depending on distance the camera has traveled). This can work because if you're further away from an object, moving doesn't cause the angle to the viewer to change as often which, in turn, means the old sorting data is more likely to be valid. I'm not a fan of this because I like algorithms which allow my game to teleport across the map without any issues. (Mind you, streaming assets from disk becomes the real issue for teleporting.)

Comment: To your first point, my scene gets rotated with the mouse, so I am assuming that I could smooth the sort out before the user would be able to rotate it 90 degrees.  For the `teleport` scenario you describe, I agree with your assessment.  But that could just be handled as a special case (with a full sort).  Those scenarios should be less often and easily enumerable (at least in my application).  My `game` is actually just an application that displays ball-and-stick diagrams...big ones.

Comment: You first point about a 90 degree rotation from along x to along causing sort to depend on x or y coordinate only - is only true in a special case - your camera angle is 180 degrees. With a 90 degree camera there is a relationship still. Example an object far in x and close in y when you look down the x axis is small and toward the end of the display list. Turning 90 degrees would just cause it to rotate off the screen. Or consider what happens with a 1 degree camera angle - no sort changes unless the scene or camera origin changes.

Answer (score 0):

[Shell sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) is good for lists with few unique values and some scenarios that "need short code and do not use the call stack".

In your case, you need something called [Adaptive sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort), which means algorithms "takes advantage of existing order in its input".

If your space is tight, you can just use Straight Insertion Sort, which is adaptive and in place.

Otherwise you can try Timsort and Smoothsort as @RunningWild suggested, they are both adaptive sort algorithms.